# How to fix Valuerror: negative seek value in flask

Tags: python, flask, openpyxl

I have a function I am writing in flask to upload a file and read from the file, but when I upload and it gets to the reading the file it throws up this error
`ValueError: negative seek value -315`
I know its from the part of the code were I attempt to read the file because if I remove that part, the file uploads successfully.

here is the code

```py
@home_blueprint.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        wb = load_workbook(f)
        sheet=wb.active
        get_row = sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,
                           min_col=1,
                           max_col=4,
                           values_only=True)

        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        return 'file uploaded successfully'
```

This is my error full stack trace

```
    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app

    response = self.handle_exception(e)

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

    raise value

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

    raise value

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    File "/home/akoh/Documents/personal/IntronHealthExercise/app/home/views.py", line 25, in upload

    wb = load_workbook(f)

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 314, in load_workbook

    reader.read()

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 279, in read

    self.read_worksheets()

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 254, in read_worksheets

    charts, images = find_images(self.archive, rel.target)

    File "/home/akoh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/drawings.py", line 24, in find_images

    src = archive.read(path)

    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1337, in read

    with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:

    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1391, in open

    fheader = zef_file.read(sizeFileHeader)

    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 728, in read

    self._file.seek(self._pos)

    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 888, in seek

    self._file.seek(*args)

    ValueError: negative seek value -315
```

Comment: can you tell what is the value of `f` after `f = request.files['file']`.  load_workbook() expects a file path and I doubt `f` provides that.

Comment: This is the value of f ```<FileStorage: 'user_unit_tenure.xlsx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')> ```

Comment: ok, so I tried your code and it is working fine. I assume the `load_workbook` function is from `openpyxl`. Can you attach your xlsx file that you are posting to this api?

Comment: yes the load_workbook is from openpyxl. I dont know how I can attach the xlsx file here?

Comment: upload it on gdrive and attach link here.

Comment: this is it https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WV7eNgC-pJ_yEnVMusx9bGoyKqr3IWxz

Comment: strangely, the code works fine on both windows and linux for your xlsx file.

Comment: Yes it works, I just discovered the file was corrupted

Comment: hahahha...great

Answer (score 2):

So the code works just fine, the problem was with the file, it was corrupted.